# Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm getting error

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.)

in netbean established the connection.

[image]

Comment: your driver/db too old? ...https://support.chartio.com/knowledgebase/unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-when-trying-to-connect-to-mariadb  https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/mysql-errors-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password.304616/ ... https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1042

Comment: Now I'm getting "Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long)" error

Comment: ..still (driver<>db) version problems: https://coderanch.com/t/674877/databases/error-connect-mysql-database (when we are still in scope of "netbeans": You have to adjust them (in addition to other system/project driver-libs): Services(Tab)>Databases>Drivers)

Answer (score 24):

The newer versions of MySQL default to caching_sha2_password. If you want to disable it then follow below steps

1. Login in to your MYSQL console as root user like below.

> eg  `mysql -u YOUR_ROOT_USER_NAME -p YOUR_ROOT_USER_PASSWORD`

2. Then execute the command by replacing `YOUR_ROOT_USER_NAME` and  `YOUR_ROOT_USER_PASSWORD`

> `ALTER USER 'YOUR_ROOT_USER_NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
>   mysql_native_password BY 'YOUR_ROOT_USER_PASSWORD'`;

You will no longer get any '`caching_sha2_password`' exception while connecting for any client after this.

Comment: After following your answer, now there is an another exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: This changes is nothing to do with Java. This answer is mainly related to the MySQL database. Typically to solve Java ClassCastException check your code,driver and java version.

@sansingh ..Check this thread for the accepted answer  for your problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131295/exception-during-connection-to-mysql-in-java

Comment: This worked for me on my MySQL 8.0.19

Comment: Note, that the said user is not necessary defined for host `localhost`. You can query which host's the user belongs with `SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;` and change `ALTER USER 'YOUR_ROOT_USER_NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
  mysql_native_password BY 'YOUR_ROOT_USER_PASSWORD';` accordingly.

Comment: This worked for me! ALTER USER 'YOUR_ROOT_USER_NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
  mysql_native_password BY 'YOUR_ROOT_USER_PASSWORD';  DB version= mysql 8.0.21

Comment: If it doesn't work at first, run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and try again

Answer (score -4):

follow these steps:

- just turn off the firewall on the system and security on control panel,
- create a new dynamic web project
- copy all the class fields and java files from the project
- add jar in build path version 8.0
- select tomcat in project facets
- copy jAR in lib
- try running jdbcconnection program

it will run.