# PHP 7.3.4 does not support caching_sha2_password

Tags: php, mysqli

I was having this issue on my symfony3 project:

```
PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
```

which is quite well-known: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa), [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931541/mysql-changing-authentication-type-from-standard-to-caching-sha2-password), [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193771/unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password) etc. It is even document on the PHP website [there](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php):

```
When running a PHP version before 7.1.16, or PHP 7.2 before 7.2.4, set MySQL 8 Server's default password plugin to mysql_native_password
```

That's why I went into the trouble of installing [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew), install php-7.3.4 through it, make it my default. However when I run `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep auth_`. I see this result:

```
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
```

The `PDO::__construct()` error has not changed of course. I don't know why `caching_sha2_password`. So why did installing php-7.3.4 did not change anything?

Comment: The [PHP mysqli requirements page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php) still says _caching_sha2_password plugin will be supported in a future PHP release_, so no PHP version seems to support _caching_sha2_password_. Obviously, short of providing an appropriate patch to PHP, you are not the only one to eventually switch back to 'mysql_native_password' auth strategy on your DB server.

Comment: I just can't believe that this is such an old issue but it hasn't been solved by PHP yet...