# SQL Exception while Connecting to Database

Tags: java, mysql

This code is throwing me error in first line after try statement ! I had mysql driver in library file no issues with that ! I am using netbeans 8.0 version !In another stackoverflow question I saw to change tomcat version ! I dont see possible class cast Exception in this code !

```
package jdbc;
import java.sql.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
public class Jdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Dust","root","32577488");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE Persons\n" +
                "(\n" +
                "PersonID int,\n" +
                "LastName varchar(255),\n" +
                "FirstName varchar(255),\n" +
                "Address varchar(255),\n" +
                "City varchar(255)\n" +
                ");");
            System.out.println("Hello world");
            while(rs.next())  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
            con.close();  

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Logs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at jdbc.Jdbc.main(Jdbc.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
    ... 15 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: No ! It is not I thoroughly went through !

Comment: but "i konw this already" (i think)...your driver doesnt match the database version/not up to date....

Comment: ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131295/exception-during-connection-to-mysql-in-java

Comment: AND, your code has (at least) one heavy bug: `+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3)` won't work on an "CREATE TABLE" statement ...and i am not even sure about the `rs.getInt(1)`... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`. It should return `0`. See [the JavaDoc for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-).

`executeQuery` is typically used for SQL select statements as indicated in the JavaDoc.

Comment: The error is at line ` Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Dust","root","32577488");`