# Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction exception with myBatis

Tags: java, sql, xml, eclipse, spring-mybatis

I'm creating a little CRUD webapp to show courses but when I try to run it it gives me this exception with a nested exception,

> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:240)
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.insertCourse(Unknown Source)
>   com.cyberx.signup.controller.CourseController.signup(CourseController.java:29)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   root cause java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

and this is my configuration for the database :

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/courses" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="gr3288235517" />
    </beans:bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.cyberx.signup.controller.model" />
        <beans:property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath*:com/cyberx/signup/mapper/*.xml" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Try this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131295/classcastexception-java-math-biginteger-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-long-on-con.